# ReactNative application not capturing unanswered calls

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have a problem with my ReactNative app, I tried everything but so far no luck. 
The app is supposed to run in the background and send info to the server after every time we have the unanswered call. The problem is that on some android devices app(eg android 8) is not capturing calls but on other devices (eg android 6) is working but after some time app stops capturing calls. Could anyone point me to the right direction?

GitHub repository: https://github.com/gnato/rn-test-missed-calls